# Ember-Data: Ember does not make the connection between two related models - DS.ActiveModelAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to retrieve a project which has a `hasMany` relationship to `projectTeams` which has a `belongsTo` relationship to `Teams`.

I am using `ActiveModelAdapter` and have followed the conventions indicated in the doc on emberjs.com. After the files have been retrieved, I checked the JSON output and it is valid according to what ember expects (foreign keys contain the `_id` suffix). However, the relationship between the models is not made.

Interesting fact though is that I can get a reference from `ProjectTeam` to both `Project` and `Team`...

For your convenience I created the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alexspeller/SwWkB/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the project team ids on the json for projects

```
    id: 1
    name: "asd"
    top_down_date: "2014-01-08"
    cape_town_date: "2014-01-23"
    created_at: "2014-01-04T16:17:59.441Z"
    updated_at: "2014-01-04T16:17:59.441Z"
    project_team_ids: [1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VHfKv/